# file transfer web service using Apache CXF

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I have created java web services for transfer file from client to server using Apache CXF, now what I want means, when I send the file to server , the server will return received file size to the client, the client will check the size with actuall file size, if there is any difference in that means , the client will resend remaining file only, for example, my file size will be 10kb, but server received only 5kb , so now client will resend remaining 5kb only. How can I achive task,I am new to web service, Kindly any one suggest me some ideas and technique please. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Hard coding ,better we can use some error check algorithms. I achieved this by using **Checksum** Algorithm for a file data.